# Jquery/JS replace text within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if I can remove some characters from the string that the below script creates:

```
$(".fileName").text()
```

The string that is created will be something like:

```
"bottom.gif (0.43KB)"
```

I want the string to be: "bottom.gif"

the issue:
the image name can be anything. The size of the image will also varry. The only constant that I have to work with are:
space after the image name
"(" before the file size 
")" after the file size

Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var text = $(".fileName").text().split(' (')[0];
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqhr/)

It splits the text string into an array everywhere this string ' (' occurs:

```
text[0] = "bottom.gif" 
text[1] = "0.43KB)"
```

and you need only text[0] for use.

*note*: If the ' (' doesn't exist it will return the whole string:

```
var text = $(".fileName").text().split('_')[0];

text[0]="bottom.gif (0.43KB)"
text[1]  error
```

so it is safe to use it with [0] and no check if the value is null.

Comment: This worked and I am going to select it as my answer, but can you please explain the logic. I would like to understand it.

Comment: the `split` function splits the string using the argument `' ('` as delimiter and it returns an array containing the substrings.. then you want to select the first item of that array since it will be the filename. `$(".fileName").text()` gets you the text of the HTML element with class="fileName" and then you perform your split on that... this could have been written in several lines but it was written in one line to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple and will work with any file name:

```
var text = "bottom.gif (0.43KB)";
text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf('(')-1);
```

[experimentX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705703/jquery-js-replace-text-within-a-string/7705727#7705727)'s solution will fail for some file names. E.g.: "bottom (here is the problem).gif (0.43KB)".

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, a little bit of regex

```
var img_name = "bottom.gif (0.43KB)".split(/[ ]\([0-9a-z\.]{0,}\)/gi)[0]
```